# git - how to get $(git_current_branch) variable from outside the git directory

Tags: bash, git, branch

I have a bash script containing the following code:

```
git -C "$1" push origin "$(git_current_branch)"
```

where `"$1"` is the git dir I am trying to push.

The problem is, I cannot get the correct `"$(git_current_branch)"` variable when I run the script from outside the git directory. I know I can just `cd` to `"$1"` before pushing, but I want a better solution (which makes my script cleaner).

Is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I prefer to do this through `git` command option, if possible.

Comment: `$(cd "$1" && git_current_branch)`?

Comment: Consider the rather simpler `git -C "$1" push origin HEAD`. The symbolic name `HEAD` resolves to your current branch. This only works for the (singular) current branch, but since that's the particular case you care about here... :-) (The more general trick of temporarily switching directories is useful in other cases.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
current_git_branch=$(git -C "$1" branch | sed  '/^\*/!d;s/\* //')
```

**explanation**

- call git in directory "$1" and print all branches
- delete all branches without * at start of line
- remove '* ' marker for current branch from line